# How do I successively decrease the number of times a value appears in a column using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append

I have a column(TESTFILE) that has x values (in this example x = 4, can it will be close to 50:

1. hello
2. good
3. job
4. today

I want the output to be:

1. hello
2. hello
3. hello
4. good
5. good
6. job

Code:

```
out1 = []
for i in range(len(testfile)):    
    n = len(testfile) - 1
    if i ==0:
        filepath = (testfile.iloc[i,0])*n
        out1.append(filepath)       
    elif i ==1:
        filepath = (testfile.iloc[i,0])* (n-1)   
        out1.append(filepath)
    else:
        filepath = (testfile.iloc[i,0])* (n-2)
        out1.append(filepath)
    print (filepath)
```

The output currently is:

1. hellohellohello
2. goodgood
3. job

How do I get my desired output? How should I change the code if the x  = 50? Cannot write more if statements. Please help out

Comment: If this is a formatting issue, maybe just add a new line `\n` where necessary, e.g. (testfile.iloc[i,0] + '\n')*n ?

Answer (score 4):

By using `repeat`

```
s.repeat(s.index.values[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[1183]: 
0    hello
1    hello
2    hello
3     good
4     good
5      job
Name: Val, dtype: object
```

Data input

```
s
Out[1182]: 
0    hello
1     good
2      job
3    today
Name: Val, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is genius!